# Visual Studio Extension built in VS2015 can't be debugged in VS2017. The "GetDeploymentPathFromVsixManifest" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

1. I made the extension in VS2015.
2. I followed [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-migrate-extensibility-projects-to-visual-studio-2017) instructions to port the extension to VS2017.

[This](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/4493/build-of-vsix-project-fails-with-msb4018-the-getde.html) told me to `Properties > VSIX > uncheck "Deploy VSIX content to experimental instance for debugging"` so I can at least build the extension but I still can't debug which makes working on it impossible.

As a temporary measure I would accept doing attach to process or some other "manual" process. I just can't do much work on this program unless the debugger is working.

Answer (score 1):

I create a simple vsix package project with vs2015 and upgrade it to vs2017 by following [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-migrate-extensibility-projects-to-visual-studio-2017), it can build, and the project is on [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlvaNEnglADDgQdHXRIRk5lRYRhj). when I try to debug the extension, I could not the find the extension on visual studio 2017.

[image]

Then I create an another vsix package by using vs2017 and set as startup project, then debug the project. I can see the extension with vs2015, I click it and can debug it.

[image]

[image]

[image]